# Encryption with PHP Phar

Tags: php, phar

Is it possible to encrypt/password-protect a Phar archive to enable closed-source software distribution?

Comment: What do you want to prevent? Users looking at the source code or users running the application?

Comment: @cweiske Wanting to have a company purchase closed-source software, get the software (PHAR archive?), and run on their own server, without being able to modify the source, only interact with it (run the code).

Answer (score 5):

Phar supports zip, and zip files can be password-protected. But you would need a monkey for typing in the zip password whenever a request comes in. So no, not useful for closed-source software.

But to make this a somewhat serious answer, no it really doesn't work:

> PHP Warning:  include(phar://phar.zip): failed to open stream: phar error: **Cannot process encrypted zip files** in zip-based phar "phar.zip" in php shell code on line 1

Answer (score 4):

> Wanting to have a company purchase closed-source software,

In that case, phar alone will not help you. Look for a bytecode compiler like [ioncube](https://www.ioncube.com/).